# PyQT5: how to grey out and inactivate line edit with state of the radio button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 and I would like to grey out and make line edit inactive when the radio button is toggled.

```
1st state (default)

(o) A

( ) B

--------------------
|///////////////////|      <- Line edit inactive and greyed out, no input allowed (default state)
--------------------


2nd state

( ) A

(o) B

--------------------
|                  |      <- Line edit active input allowed 
--------------------
```

Any ideas? thank you!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `radioButton.toggled.connect(lineEdit.setEnabled)` or `radioButton.toggled.connect(lineEdit.setDisabled)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each button emits a [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal whenever it's clicked and changed.

I would add a slot that connects to the lower button's toggled signal, then grays out the text box or enables it depending on the state of the button.

Comment: And this function would be: `line_edit.setEnabled(not radio_button.isChecked())`.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect the QLineEdit's `setDisabled` function to the QRadioButton's `toggled` Signal:

```py
radio_button_a.toggled.connect(line_edit.setDisabled)
```

This works, because the `toggled` signal of QRadioButton emits the current state of the radio button as `bool` (see [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled)) and the `setDisabled()` function takes exactly one `bool` ([Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setDisabled)).

Additionally, you'll have to make sure that the initial disabled state of the LineEdit matches the initial check state of your RadioButtons. If you want to take further actions on toggling of the RadioButtons, you'll need to write an own Slot (callback function) as suggested by @GandhiGandhi.